# wordpress themes demo file importing problem?

Tags: themes, server

I have installed new theme on WordPress through `wp-admin`and when i am trying to import theme demo file its showing this error

> 504 gateway timeout server not responding on time.

Comment: A "theme demo file" is not a native feature of WordPress - what is this file and how are you trying to "import" it?

Comment: xml file which is created by theme author, having all data like pages, post, media library images,comments, i am trying this from my admin panel tools/import/word-press run importer and then select file.